# How to set attribute value in p-calendar angular?

Tags: angular, primeng, angular2-template, angular2-forms, primeng-calendar

**I am using p-calendar for date selection. Now, I want to set class attribute on condition bases. For set attribute I am using setElementAttribute function but its giving me error `'vendor.bundle.js:70655 TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of undefined '`. It works in normal input or select tag but not in p-calendar tag.**

This is HTML code

```html
<p-calendar [showIcon]="true" 
            name="date" 
            id="dateId" 
            #date 
            [(ngModel)]="dateValue"
            [required]="isRequired" 
            autoClear="true" 
            (onSelect)="selectedDate(date.value)" 
            [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
            (data)="refreshValue($event)" 
            dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" 
            hourFormat="24">
</p-calendar>
```

This is ts file code

```js
@ViewChild('date ') date : any;

selectedDate(date) { 

    if (date != null) { 

          this._renderer.setElementAttribute(this.date.nativeElement, 'class', 'form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched');
      } else {
        if(this.isRequired){
          this._renderer.setElementAttribute(this.date.nativeElement, 'class', 'form-control ng-touched ng-dirty ng-invalid');
          this.Flag = false;
        }
      }
  }
```

This is error

[image]

Comment: If this is your actual code `@ViewChild('date ')` there is an extra space that will fail the lookup.

Comment: No in actual code there is no space @ViewChild('date').